# AES Encryption producing different results between PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

Hi there StackOverflow community,

After researching for countless of hours, I'm unable to find an explanation as to why my ouputs differ between javascript and my laravel application.

I could use input type hidden to make a post from my web browser, but that would defeat the purpose of having a secure client side processing and I fear that if I don't find the reason as to why this is happening, then decryption (which I plan to do through php) would not work either.

my php code is as follows:

```
    $payload = "this is my plaintext";
    $binary_signature = "";
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents(storage_path('privatekey.pem')), 'enc123456789');
    openssl_sign($payload, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    $signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);
    $new_payload = $payload."&sign=".$signature; // where my actual plaintext is also used in my javascript code
    $key = "thisismykey";
    $iv = "\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0";
    $encryption = openssl_encrypt($new_payload, 'AES-256-CBC', $key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    dd(base64_encode($encyrption));
```

which outputs the following:

```
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
```

My JS Code (the plaintext is received through an ajax call which has the same sign method as you see from the php code, the encryption plaintext is of the same value from my php code)

```
            function encrypt(plaintext, secretkey) {
  
            var randomSeed = "";
            randomSeed = secretkey;
            var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomSeed.toUpperCase());
            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("0000000000000000");
            var encrypt = {};
            encrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {
                mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                iv : iv
            });
            console.log("encryption is "+encrypt.toString());
            return encrypt.toString(encrypt.toString());
        }
```

Returns the correct value which is:

```
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
```

I don't understand **why my PHP encryption is giving the wrong output while my JavaScript encryption is giving the correct output**

I'm hoping someone could give me an insight as to what I'm doing wrong from my PHP side. Wha I'm hoping to achieve is that my PHP encryption will output the same result as my JavaScript encryption.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("0000000000000000");` looks like the IV is a bunch of zero characters `\x30` while the PHP IV is a bunch of null bytes `\x00`. Try changing the PHP IV to the same string of zeroes. Additionally, IVs should be random and unique per-message, are not considered secrets, and are frequently packed into the leading bytes of the ciphertext.

Comment: Hi Sammitch, I did try that with hex2bin("0000000000000000") and even with just $iv = "0000000000000000" but both result in the same output. And yes I do know that iv is to be random, however, the project im working on requires the iv to be 16 chars of 0 for some validation from a third party integration

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.

To those having a similar issue, here's a brief explanation. Crypto JS uses the following:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomSeed.toUpperCase());
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("0000000000000000");
```

Which translates to a word array if you console log the output. PHP needs to have the similar word array value that cryptoJS produces for it's AES encryption method. To solve this, you have to convert your $key and iv to be in hex format and format your code in php such as:

```
$key = pack("H*", "4a424d56595753555047553830334d42505a314f414256414c5a565239324659");
$iv = pack("H*", "30303030303030303030303030303030");
```

Then when you proceed to using openssl_encrypt

```
$encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

you will get the same output as crpytoJS.
Hope this helps.